# one to one private chat how to emit message using user id?

Tags: socket.io

I wanna send private one - to - one messages instead of broadcast to all users ? and socket id is random so how i can save chat history to database ? How i can use my mysql userid to send message privately by replacing broadcast  , kindly guide me in how to store chat history by user id and send private message .

```js
const socket = io() ;
sessionStorage.getItem('status');
sessionStorage.getItem('email');
sessionStorage.getItem('userid');
let mesgebox= document.getElementById("chatbox");


function Sendmessages()
{
    var message = document.getElementById("textareamessagebox").value;
    console.log(message);
    let msg ={
        userid:sessionStorage.getItem('userid'),
        msg:message.trim(),
    }
    appendMessage(msg,"outgoing")
    document.getElementById("textareamessagebox").value='';
    scrolltobottom();
    /*send to server*/
    socket.emit("message",msg)
}
 function appendMessage(msg,type)
 {
    console.log(msg.msg);
    console.log(msg.userid);
    let messagebody =document.createElement('div');
    messagebody.className="cardxxx";
    let userinfo =document.createElement('div');
    userinfo.className="userinfo";
    let userinfoimg =document.createElement('img');
    userinfoimg.className="userinfoimg";
    let divmargin =document.createElement('div');
    divmargin.className="divmargin";
    let username =document.createElement('h4');
    username.className="username";
    let msgtime =document.createElement('p');
    msgtime.className="msgtime";
    let msgview =document.createElement('p');
    msgview.className="msgview";
    username.innerText=msg.userid;
    msgview.innerText="12.34";
    msgview.innerText=msg.msg;

    userinfo.appendChild(userinfoimg);
    divmargin.appendChild(username);
    divmargin.appendChild(msgtime);
    divmargin.appendChild(msgview);

    messagebody.appendChild(userinfo);
    messagebody.appendChild(divmargin);
    mesgebox.appendChild(messagebody);
 }

 /* Recive Message */

 socket.on('message',(msg)=>{
    appendMessage(msg,"type");
    scrolltobottom()
 })

 function scrolltobottom()
 {
    mesgebox.scrollTop = mesgebox.scrollHeight
 }
```